# Dynamically adding types to a jaxb context

Tags: java, plugins, jaxb, rcp

I have multiple plug-ins in my RCP-based project. I want to be able to define @XMLElements in one plug-in that can then be marshaled / un-marshaled from the core plugin. To do so, I report the classes that are serializable as soon as the plug-in is loaded. However, dynamically adding classes seems to be not supported by the JAXBContext. I implemented a work-around by holding all classes in a list and creating a new JAXBContext every time some new classes are reported based on that list, but this solution is not really nice.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely can not add classes dynamically to a JAXBContext.  This has to do with maintaining the thread safety of JAXBContext.

I have recently posted an example on [my blog](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/) explaining how to leverage the @XmlAnyElement annotation to generate a generic message that could have different payloads:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

**Root Object**

The root element for the body property will be controlled by that objects @XmlRootElement.

```
package message;   

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;   

@XmlRootElement@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class Message {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String to;       

    @XmlAttribute    
    private String from;       

    @XmlAnyElement    
    private Object body;   
}
```

**Creating the JAXBContext**

Instead of creating the JAXBContext on an array of classes, the JAXBContext could be created on a context path:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance("message:customer:product");
```

This context path includes 3 package names seperated by the colon ':' character.  In each of these packages we need to include a file named jaxb.index with a list of files.  Below is an example of the jaxb.index file in the customer package:

```
Address
Customer
```

When we want to add a model to represent orders to our framework we would extend our JAXBContext creation to like (this String could be passed in as a variable):

```
JAXBContext.newInstance("message:customer:product:order");
```